Difference between Phase Diagram and Convex Hull
in literature I sometimes see a mixed use of the words Phase Diagram and Convex Hull. However from my current knowledge, there are some differences between them.
A phase diagram views the difference in Gibbs free energy and is in principal a function $\Delta G = \Delta G (p,T,\{x_i\})$, where $\{x_i\}$ are concentrations of all competing elements. However, a phase diagram only shows equilibrium phases, i.e. that minimize the Gibbs free energy difference. Tie lines come from the overlap of competing phases and yield to mixed phases.
So what is the Convex Hull in this context ? For a convex hull I have to theoretically calculate for each concentration the $\Delta G$ for each possible phase. This is an infinite large problem. But in the end the convex hull is just a geometric construction and does not show phase components, right ? So what does it exactly show ? Why would I need it in any way?
